# How to store a Keras .h5 file in a Django database?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have several Keras .h5 files that I want to store using a Django model. In the Django docs there is no model field designed for .h5 files. Is there and way I can convert it to a json and store it as that or is there another go to way for doing this?

Comment: Store the files using a FileField?

Comment: I have tired this and in didn't work

Comment: FileFields work just fine for this, I suspect you just didn't use them correctly here. However, using FileFields the data itself will not be stored in your database, which may be an advantage or a disadvantage, depending on what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

there is a package called [django-picklefield](https://pypi.org/project/django-picklefield/) I had used that for the same purpose to store NumPy in Django models.
this package will save pickles as blobs in the database.
if the h5 data file is binary too you can use this package with a little modification.
another way is you can store your data in a pickle file instead of h5 its a bit faster than h5 too

Comment: "a bit faster" to do what? Pickle files must be entirely decoded; h5 files don't need to be, for one...